# Terrain/plane with an aerial photo on it

Tags: mesh, texturing

We work with Lumion and I want to make an golf course.

Lumion accept only 3D materials so we have to build a terrain in a 3rd party 3d software. Is it possible to make a plane/mesh about 2x2 km and paste an image of a golf course on the plane, then export the 3d terrain as in an .skp, .fbx, .dae, or .obj format to Lumion?

Are there some tutorials to follow?

Many thanks!

Barry

Comment: Blender supports many formats, you can, of course, export your models to fbx, dae and obj, but do you need just a simple plane with texture on it, or you need to apply a height map? You can do both in Blender, but the answer "how-to" will be different.

Comment: Note that there are no 3D materials in Blender. Blender applies 2D materials to the surfaces of a 3D object.

Comment: Are you talking about a scan like LYDAR or is it a photo?